# What is the date mentioned in @@version SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I wanted to know what the date that is result of select @@vesion in SQL server refers to.

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)   *May 14 2014 18:34:29*   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the SQL Server build date for the installed version. Refer to [@@version on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177512(v=sql.110).aspx).