# how to find out if I am in azure or not?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, azure-sql-database, azure, environment-variables

I am talking about sql server here.

I can [connect to azure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/178180/22336).
I can also [manage permissions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/228421/22336).

But while doing some automation, I need to know if I am in [azure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/290563/22336) or normal sql.
how can I achieve that?

I have been using the [@@version](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/120949/22336). However, [it is said it is not accurate](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/284221/22336).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option could be [EngineEdition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16) .

Try:

```
SELECT CASE ServerProperty('EngineEdition')
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Personal'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'Standard'
         WHEN 3 THEN 'Enterprise'
         WHEN 4 THEN 'Express'
         WHEN 5 THEN 'SQL Database'
         WHEN 6 THEN 'Azure Synapse Analytics'
         WHEN 8 THEN 'Azure SQL Managed Instance'
         WHEN 9 THEN 'Azure SQL Edge'
         WHEN 11 THEN 'Azure Synapse serverless SQL pool'
       END
```

*Note*. There are different ways of getting the SQL Server version on the link above using SERVERPROPERTY.

Another simpler method:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN ServerProperty('Edition') = 'SQL Azure'
         THEN 'Azure'
         ELSE 'No Azure' END AS server_version;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c10db6e4d5def947657b780ede48fee1

Answer (score 1):

at the moment July/2022 I am using the following script.
I have a few machines in azure, and sql server 2016,2017 and 2019.

```
set nocount on

DECLARE @version  varchar(20)
SELECT  @version = convert(varchar, serverproperty('ProductVersion'))

IF @version NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9].%'
   SELECT @version = '0' + @version

PRINT @version


IF @version < '09.00.3042'
   RAISERROR('dbo.sp_showADGroups requires SQL Server 2005 SP2 or later', 16, 127)

select [version is] = @version, 
@@VERSION

SELECT @Version=left(@Version,2)

SELECT [@Version]=@Version

IF @VERSION = '12' 
   PRINT 'We are in Azure'
ELSE
   PRINT 'Not Azure'


 SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition')
 --this returns 8 in azure
 -- this returns 2 in sql 2019
 --this returns 3 in sql 2016
```

the query above returns the following - in azure:

[image]